# how to remove all subset from a list of list

Tags: python, list

what is the efficient way to clean sublist in list . cause I only want to got the biggest set in list. just like.

```
b = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [3,5], [2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [1,2,4,6,7]]
```

and I want the output as follow.

```
result = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [1,2,4,6,7]]
```

Cause [1,2] is subset of [1,2,3] and [1,2,4,6,7], [3,5] is subset of [3,4,5], and also [2,3,4] appear 2 times, only want calculate 1 time in final result. I want to based on the subset logical to filter data.

I only think out 2 loops solution to solve this problem, but if there is other efficient way to solve this problem.

what I tried like that: (after I optimising this one more effect, add break and add 1 part not calculate 2 times)

```
b = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [3,5], [2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [1,2,4,6,7]]
i = 0
record = []
subset_status = False
for index, re in enumerate(b):
    while i <= (len(b)-1):
        if i != index:
            if i not in record:
                if set(re).issubset(b[i]):
                    subset_status = True
                    break
        i += 1
    i = 0
    if subset_status:
        record.append(index)
        subset_status = False
print(record)
>>[1, 2, 3]
```

So I got the index in [1,2,3] is the dirty data.
Thanks.

Comment: What are the conditions for a "clean" list? Has to have 3 elements?

Comment: Why not just initialize b to be what you want? `b = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]`

Comment: @RedCricket this is the other way, but I want to from other angle to solve my problem, so I meet this problem.

Comment: @Loocid Sorry, I am not native speaker, so for me, I think the sublist in b e.g. [1,2],[3,5] is the dirty data in my original list, so I want to clean them. Could you give me other advise how to change my question title can make it better?

Comment: Explain what makes `[1,2]` and `[3,5]` dirty. as well as what you've tried.

Comment: @Sayse thank you remind me. I put my reason why this 2 are dirty.

Comment: uh …  how is `[1,2,4,6,7], [3,5]` a subset of` `[3,4,5]`.

Comment: @RedCricket, There should be an "and" in-between.  :)

Comment: Hmmm. I don't fully understand the logic by which you want to filter the sublists. Can you make another example or describe the condition more rigorously?

Comment: @RedCricket this are 2 different [1,2] is subset of [1,2,3] and [1,2,4,6,7].  then [3,5] is subset of [3,4,5]

Comment: So in other words, you don't want to take any sublists that are contained in any previously seen list? If so, what about order and repeated elements?

Comment: I think @Starry wants to remove anything that is a subset of any element in the list.

Comment: You should show what you've tried.

Comment: @timgeb I put the code what I tried and the result what i want

Comment: anyways … given a list of list of integers it would be fun to figure out how to remove all list that are subsets of the other list.

Comment: @RedCricket haha, I think I need put more detail at first, that not make other confuse. cause I find it hard to me share what I think about properly

Comment: Yes it is unclear what you are trying to do. Can you write what you want in pseudo code?

Comment: @RedCricket how about now, I revised my question based on what 'Sayse' remind me.

Comment: So you do want to remove all subset from a list of list. Right? You might want to give more than just one example. If you are unable to articulate what you want via English try using pseudo code like, `f([[1]]) -> [[1]], f([[1][1,2]]) -> [[1,2]], f([[1][1,2],[3]]) -> [[1,2],[3]], f([[1][1,2,3],[3]]) -> [[1,2,3]]` and so on until it is very clear what you want.

Comment: @RedCricket Thanks a lot. Next time I know how to explain well. haha, by this way not receive a lot inverted triangles.

Comment: Well it is very difficult to have to express oneself in a foreign language. I am certain that you are better at expressing yourself in English than I could in any other language than English. Hey let's all learn Esperanto. :)

Comment: @RedCricket haha, now I still work on how to optimise my solution.

Answer (score 1):

A conditional [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is a pythonic, flexible and performant approach. It is usually faster and less error prone to assemble the clean list from scratch than to repeatedly remove elements:

```
b = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [3, 5], [2, 3, 4],[3, 4, 5]]

cleaned = [x for x in b if clean(x)]  # where clean is your condition
# e.g.
cleaned = [x for x in b if len(x) == 3] 
# [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

If you need to mutate the original `list` object, use slice assignment:

```
b[:] = [x for x in b if clean(x)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to based on length of sublist. The logic I revised in my question. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`filter` your list on condition:

```
b = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [3,5], [2,3,4],[3,4,5]]

print(list(filter(lambda x: len(x) == 3, b)))
# [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don`t by the right way to represent my question, I don`t want to based on the length of sublist.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to process the lists in `b` in order of length, from longest to shortest.

```
b = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [3,5], [2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [1,2,4,6,7]]
result = []
for u in sorted(map(set, b), key=len, reverse=True):
    if not any(u <= v for v in result):
        result.append(u)
print(result)
```

**output**

```
[{1, 2, 4, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}]
```

If you need to keep the inner lists as actual lists, and you also need to preserve the order, then we can do that with an additional pass over the data. But instead of using a list for `result` I'll use a set to make the tests more efficient. And that means turning the sublists into frozensets: plain sets won't work because only hashable objects can be put into a set.

```
b = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [3,5], [2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [1,2,4,6,7]]
temp = set()
for u in sorted(map(frozenset, b), key=len, reverse=True):
    if not any(u <= v for v in temp): 
        temp.add(u)
newb = []
for u in b: 
    if set(u) in temp and u not in newb:
        newb.append(u)
print(newb)
```

**output**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not very good, but it works:

```
result = []
for i in b:
    for j in result:
        if all(c in j for c in i):
            break
    else:
        new_list.append(i)

for i in result:
    for j in result:
        if all(c in j for c in i) and result.index(i) != result.index(j):
            del(result[result.index(i)])
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *tuples* and *product* to detect if item is a sublist, then construct a new list excluding those sublist

*list comprehension*

```
from itertools import product

b = [[1,2,3], [1,2], [3,5], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [1,2,4,6,7]]

dirty = [i for i in b for j in b if i != j if tuple(i) in product(j, repeat = len(i))]
clean = [i for i in b if i not in dirty]
```

Expanded explanation:

```
dirty = []
for i in b:
    for j in b:
        if i != j:
            if tuple(i) in product(j, repeat = len(i)):
                dirty.append(i)

clean = [i for i in b if i not in dirty]
```

> ```
> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]]
> ```

Comment: thanks, but your way can not work for complex situation. if [2,3,4] appear 2 times in b, you can not filter out one of them. and also this one solution till need go through b 2 times. Not more effect as what i use now.  thanks, again